# Transposing a column into three new columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql with the following columns:

[image]

Example of data:

```
'16', '1', 'Evening', '6.00', '2014-06-05 08:14:35', '2014-06-04', '6.00'
'17', '2', 'Afternoon', '8.00', '2014-06-05 08:15:29', '2014-06-04', '8.00'
'18', '3', 'Afternoon', '4.00', '2014-06-05 08:17:32', '2014-06-04', '4.00'
'19', '4', 'Afternoon', '4.00', '2014-06-05 08:18:25', '2014-06-04', '4.00'
'20', '17', 'Morning', '2.00', '2014-06-05 09:11:40', '2014-06-05', '2.00'
'21', '17', 'Morning', '3.00', '2014-06-05 09:16:36', '2014-06-04', '3.00'
'22', '17', 'Evening', '2.00', '2014-06-05 09:17:43', '2014-06-04', '2.00'
'23', '19', 'Morning', '1.00', '2014-06-05 10:12:47', '2014-06-05', '1.00'
'24', '20', 'Morning', '2.00', '2014-06-05 10:16:02', '2014-06-05', '2.00'
'25', '22', 'Morning', '2.00', '2014-06-05 10:27:34', '2014-06-05', '2.00'
'26', '23', 'Morning', '2.00', '2014-06-05 10:28:08', '2014-06-05', '2.00'
'27', '24', 'Morning', '1.00', '2014-06-05 10:30:20', '2014-06-05', '1.00'
'28', '27', 'Morning', '1.00', '2014-06-05 10:43:12', '2014-06-05', '1.00'
'29', '27', 'Combined', '2.00', '2014-06-05 10:45:45', '2014-06-04', '2.00'
'31', '28', 'Morning', '3.00', '2014-06-05 11:04:32', '2014-06-05', '3.00'
```

I would like to transpose the time column so that I have three new columns evening, afternoon and morning and record the quantity so that columns look like
`id, cow_id, Evening, Afternoon, Morning, date_added, date,quantity_type`

Could someone give me a solution on how to go about this with mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all a cow's feeds for a given date on one line, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT cow_id, 
    SUM(CASE time WHEN 'Evening' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Evening,
    SUM(CASE time WHEN 'Afternoon' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Afternoon,
    SUM(CASE time WHEN 'Morning' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Morning,
    SUM(CASE time WHEN 'Combined' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Combined,
    `date`
FROM cows
GROUP BY cow_id, date
```

For your sample data, this would give a result like this (note I had to add another column for the 'Combined' time):

```
cow_id  Evening Afternoon   Morning Combined    date    
1       6       0           0       0           2014-06-04  
2       0       8           0       0           2014-06-04  
3       0       4           0       0           2014-06-04  
4       0       4           0       0           2014-06-04  
17      2       0           3       0           2014-06-04  
17      0       0           2       0           2014-06-05  
19      0       0           1       0           2014-06-05  
20      0       0           2       0           2014-06-05  
22      0       0           2       0           2014-06-05  
23      0       0           2       0           2014-06-05  
27      0       0           0       2           2014-06-04  
27      0       0           1       0           2014-06-05  
28      0       0           3       0           2014-06-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, cow_id,
    IF(time = 'Morning',quantity,0) AS Morning,
    IF(time = 'Afternoon',quantity,0) AS Afternoon,
    IF(time = 'Evening',quantity,0) AS Evening,
    date_added, quantity_type
FROM OriginalTable
```

It works by only including the `quantity` if the `time` matches the particular value and then aliases the column name to make the output prettier.

Comment: Fixed now, @Used_By_Already ! I was having trouble getting the code layout tag to work at all for some reason.